# Select all information about most common occurrence in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select all information of the employee who manages the most other employees.

My table is here:

| eID | fName | lName | Job | Manager | Hired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Adam | Smith | Manager | 102 | 1998-04-12 |
| 102 | Eliza | Rynd | Manager | 101 | 1999-03-07 |
| 103 | Imran | Khan | Sales | 102 | 2003-04-17 |

The values in Manager are eID's

The below returns null, should I be using a Max count instead?

```
SELECT TOP 1 Manager, COUNT(Manager)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Manager
```

**Expected output**

```
eID fName   lName   Job     Manager Hired
102 Eliza   Rynd    Manager 101     1999-03-07 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Pls give us your sample data and expected result :

Comment: Just added all the daya @NguyễnVănPhong Expected result is show all info about Eliza because she manages the most people.

Comment: Please actually show your expected result - rather than expecting people to read through the comments.

Comment: `The below returns null` Based on the sample data that you have provided, that query does not return `NULL` value.

Comment: I dont think `Manager` of `Eliza` is `101`?

Comment: What if there are two such managers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to separate the logic and get the manager with the highest count, in the event two managers manage the same number of employees, use `with ties`, otherwise one will be exluded.

```
with x as (
    select top (1) with ties Manager
    from Table
    group by Manager
    order by Count(*) desc
)
select *
from x join Table t on t.eId=x.Manager
```

Comment: This is the best explanation so far - however an important explanation should also be added why `"should I be using a Max count instead"` can not be achieved (assuming it would be `MAX(COUNT(...))`.

Comment: You cannot nest aggregate functions, that's just invalid syntax.

Comment: I know that - but the OP seem not to, as I quoted from the question. Possibly also needs an explanation why `ORDER BY` is a must.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `ORDER BY` clause in your query to get the manager with the most employees.
Use it as a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE eID = (
  SELECT TOP 1 Manager
  FROM Employee
  GROUP BY Manager
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
```

If you want ties returned, then use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` in the query and the operator `IN` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE eID IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Manager
  FROM Employee
  GROUP BY Manager
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8780b91f8139a310d7a44fbc42ec5f04).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to get all `"manages the most other employees"`

```
SELECT *
FROM @Employee
WHERE eID IN (SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties Manager 
                  FROM @Employee
                  GROUP BY Manager
                  ORDER BY COUNT(Manager) DESC)
```

**Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45d1d420916f89427b881d952952408a)**

**Output**

```
eID fName   lName   Job     Manager Hired
102 Eliza   Rynd    Manager 101     1999-03-07 00:00:00.000
```